# How to enable App Store promotions for In-app purchases for ionic application?

Tags: ionic-framework, in-app-purchase, ionic4, appstore-approval

I am not able use **App Store Promotions** to promote my in-app purchases because the binary doesn’t include the SKPaymentTransactionObserver method as shown below:

> These in-app purchases can’t be promoted on the App Store because your latest approved binary doesn’t include the
>   SKPaymentTransactionObserver method.

The application is developed using **Ionic4**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two way for in-app-purchase in ionic, namely [**In App Purchase**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase) and [**In App Purchase 2**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase-2). In principle, the implementation of **In App Purchase** don't support App Store Promotions and hence SKPaymentTransactionObserver method is not supported (still to date an open issue in the plugin repository [issue 172](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase/issues/172)).

To get the support for App Store Promotions the developer must use the [**In App Purchase 2**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase-2) which supports the promotions as indicated in [issue 608](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/issues/608).